# date - years prior to 1901 are treated as invalid

Tags: shell-script, date

I have date (GNU coreutils) 7.1 installed on my system.

If I try to check dates prior to 14-Dec-1901, I get an "invalid date" error. For example,

```
  $ date -d 1901-12-13
  date: invalid date `1901-12-13'

  $ date -d 1901-12-14
  Sat Dec 14 00:00:00 EST 1901
```

What should I do to make the `date` utility to treat years prior to 1901 as valid?

I receive similar errors for dates after 19-Jan-2038

Comment: I receive no error. I'm using coreutils 8.10, maybe an old bug?

Comment: @xenoterracide are you an a 64-bit system?

Comment: @Mikel yes, I am

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question.

The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Calendar-date-items) says it should be allowed.

```
 info date 'Date input formats' 'Calendar date items'
```

> For numeric months, the ISO 8601 format `YEAR-MONTH-DAY' is allowed,
>   where YEAR is any positive number, ...
>
> A leading zero must be present if a number is less than ten.
>
> If YEAR is 68 or smaller, then 2000 is added to it; otherwise, if YEAR is less than 100, then 1900 is added to it.

Are you on a 32-bit system?

Do you get an error with dates after 2038-01-20 as well, e.g.

```
date -d '2038-01-20'
```

If so, it sounds like GNU date is using a 32-bit time value.

I'm not sure how you can fix this other than using a 64-bit system or using a different tool, for example [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) in Perl or [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) in Python.

Some background:

Unix times count the number of seconds from January 1 1970 using an integer value.  If the system uses 32-bit integers, it can only count 2.1 billion seconds forward (up to 2038-01-19 03:14:02 UTC) and 2.1 billion seconds backwards (back to 1901-12-13 20:45:52 UTC).

More information at:

- [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch)
- [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)
- [1901 (Significance of 1901 for Modern Computers)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1901#Significance_of_1901_for_modern_computers)

Comment: Thanks Mikel, i believe so that i'm on a 32 bit machine. Actually, i'm working a remote server and the server wont reveal much information even with `uname` command except the fact that it says its an i686 machine, which i assume are 32 bit machines. As for the 2038 problem, yes, that problem is there infact in the remote server. Thanks again for your input! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, i686 is 32-bit.  Glad to help.  If you need help dealing with dates older than that, try the Python and Perl modules I suggested, and post another question if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 7):

Your system (or at least that version of *date*) is probably using a 32-bit internal time value.

The Unix epoch (zero time value) is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. This starting point puts 1901-12-13 00:00 EST just outside the range of a signed 32-bit time value.

1901-12-14 00:00:00 EST is -2147454000
1901-12-13 15:45:52 EST is -2147483648 (aka `INT_MIN` in C, the minimum 32-bit signed integer)
1901-12-13 00:00:00 EST is -2147540400

You could try using 1901-12-13 15:45:52 EST. It should work, but one second earlier will probably fail in the same way as 1901-12-13 00:00.